# Broken link to Area 51 "What's Meta" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

When I log into the discussion zone of Area 51 and click on `Help` > [`What's Meta?`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), the linked page `area51.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta` cannot be found. I guess this should be fixed.

Comment: It's missing a redirect, the other two Help items redirect to http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We won't show that link at all as of next build.

There are already two links in the Help dropdown that take folks to /faq on Area 51, so a third one really isn't necessary. Not to mention that "meta" as a concept doesn't really apply to Area 51.